# How to Edit a Read-Only Word Document (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, readonly

I am periodically getting Word documents from various clients and sometimes they send them to me in 'Read-Only' mode. While it isn't a big deal to go to 'View > Edit Document' manually, I cannot seem to find how to do this within my VBA code.

Either opening a document as editable or toggling it as editable once it is open would be sufficient for my needs.

Note that I cannot open the document with 'readOnly = false' as it looks like it is set to 'readOnly recommended' (based on my reading of the MS man page on Document.Open).

IN CONTEXT:
I was also hitting a problem with turning off 'read-mode' which the documents were opening as by default. I have posted this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419019/how-to-edit-a-word-document-that-opens-in-read-mode-in-vba/47419062#47419062).

Comment: You would need to open the document `Read Only` and `SaveAs` an editable document. Use the `Kill` command to delete the original file.

Comment: @Variatus, Can you please elaborate on what command fags I need to perform a SaveAs to an editable document? Here is what I have tried that didn't work (new document was also opened as read-only):
<code>
`Set oWd = Documents.Open(origFile)`

`oWd.SaveAs2 FileName:=newFile, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False`

`oWd.Close`
`Set oWd = Documents.Open(newFile)`
</code>

Comment: Also, sorry I couldn't figure out the linebreaks for my comment :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will change the ReadOnly attribute of a closed file, setting its ReadOnly attribute to either True or False depending on the argument supplied to the procedure.

```
Private Sub SetReadOnlyProperty(Fn As String, _
                                ByVal ReadOnly As Boolean)
    ' 21 Nov 2017

    Dim Fso As Object
    Dim Doc As Object

    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Doc = Fso.GetFile(Fn)

    If (Doc.Attributes And vbReadOnly) <> Abs(Int(ReadOnly)) Then
        Doc.Attributes = Doc.Attributes Xor vbReadOnly
    End If
End Sub
```

This procedure requires access to the MS Scripting Runtime DLL. Enable this access by checking the box against `Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime` from Tools >References in the VBE window. Below is an example of how to call the function. Note that an error will result if the supplied file doesn't exist.

```
Private Sub TestReadOnly()
    SetReadOnlyProperty "H:\Test Folder\Test File.docx", False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Variatus. 
Can you comment at all on what dangers there are in enabling this Reference? I.e. I have gotten bit before with other references not working on other workstations when I release my tools. I believe some of the workstations I run my tools on have tighter security policies too that disable some DLL's (as best as I can tell)...so I may actually have less references to work with than a 'baseline' 2010/2013 MS Office deployment...

Comment: I'm not an authority on this subject. However I believe that all Microsoft DLLs are safe. Some of them are not loaded by default to enable faster loading. `Scripting Runtime` has some objects not included in other VBA DLLs you wouldn't even ask about. It's when you come to custom DLLs that you should be careful. BTW, I think the reference to `Scripting Runtime` is saved with the document, and the DLL itself is part of the Office installation. Therefore you wouldn't have to enable the reference on every computer.